# Uncaught ReferenceError: openModal is not defined in js active admin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

add function in coffeescript and onclick to my code in active admin but function is not defined

my function in modal.js.coffee :

```
openModal = ->
  if $('#myModal').length > 0
    $('#myModal')[0].style.display = 'blok'
  return
```

activeadmin admin view :

```
image_tag(image.image.url(:thumb), class: 'default-img-thumb hover-shadow', onclick: "openModal();currentSlide("+image.position.to_s+")")
```

anybody can help me ?

Comment: $('#myModal')[0].style.display = 'blok'....- block - spelling mistakes

Comment: thanks for response. i think this error in value display same with you. i try to change blok become block but still error openModal is not defined